# Zhuyin input settings in WIndows 8

Tags: windows-8, input-languages, chinese, language-bar

I own a transformer tablet with a Chinese (Taiwanese) version of Windows 8. I'd like to use it to type Chinese characters using the installed Zhuyin input method, but as it is the input method requires me to input the right tone for every single character (including the first tone).

Chinese is not my native language and it is extremely cumbersome for me to input every single tone as I often have to stop and try to remember the exact pronunciation. Truth be said, I believe it would be at best inconvenient even for native speakers to type in this way as it increase the required amount of typing by a good third for every word.

Looking in the Taiwanese internet all I could find is some registry key to enable other input interfaces, but if I try to paste them to the registry these methods while appearing in the language settings don't appear to be selectable (only the "remove" button is enabled).

Does anyone have experience with setting up Zhuyin input methods in Windows 8 or at least in importing new input profiles (the additional profiles available in the Windows language settings are greyed out and the Taiwanese users are protesting without any answer about it.. ).

Comment: I assume we are dealing with Windows 8 Single Language so the chances of installing a different language pack is not an option?

Comment: I just installed and switched to English with no downloads involved so I'd say this is a multi-language version. But the problem is the input method (typing non-latin characters has its own set of sub-options).